# Having some issues implementing a ActionListener in a SudokuSolver program

Tags: java

`

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class UI {
    SudokuBoard board;
    JTextField[][] grid;
    JFrame frame;

    public UI(SudokuBoard board) {
        this.board = board;
        this.grid = new JTextField[9][9];
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createWindow("SudokuGame", 1000, 1000));
    }

    private void createWindow(String title, int width, int height) {
        // creating main window
        this.frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        // creating buttons
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton solve = new JButton("Solve");
        JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
        buttonPanel.add(solve);
        buttonPanel.add(clear);
        pane.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        solve.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (board.solve()) {
                updateBoard();
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Unsolvable Board");
            }
        });
        clear.addActionListener(e -> {
            board.clear();
            updateBoard();
        });

        // creating game grid
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(9, 9));
        topPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        Font font = new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 80);
        for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
                JTextField temp = new JTextField(1);
                temp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
                temp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
                temp.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
                temp.setFont(font);
                temp.addActionListener(new SetAction(row, col, temp, board));

                if (((col < 3 || col > 5) && (row < 3 || row > 5)) || col > 2 && col < 6 && row > 2 && row < 6) {
                    temp.setBackground(new Color(91, 166, 209));
                } else {
                    temp.setBackground(new Color(181, 197, 209));
                }
                grid[row][col] = temp;
                topPanel.add(temp);
            }
        }
        pane.add(topPanel);

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        updateBoard();

    }

    private void updateBoard() {
        int[][] temp = board.getMatrix();
        for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
                if (temp[row][col] == 0) {
                    grid[row][col].setText("");
                } else {
                    grid[row][col].setText(Integer.toString(temp[row][col]));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class SetAction implements ActionListener {
        private int row, col;
        private SudokuBoard board;
        private JTextField text;

        public SetAction(int r, int c, JTextField text, SudokuBoard board) {
            row = r;
            col = c;
            this.text = text;
            this.board = board;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String inp = text.getText();
            board.set(row, col, Integer.parseInt(inp));     
        }
    }

}
```

`

`

```
public class SudokuBoard implements SudokuSolver {
    int[][] board;

    public SudokuBoard() {
        int[][] temp = {
                { 7, 0, 2, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0 },
                { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 5, 0, 0 },
                { 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0 },
                { 0, 4, 3, 0, 0, 0, 7, 5, 0 },
                { 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8 },
                { 0, 0, 9, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5 },
                { 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0, 3 } };
        board = temp;
    }

    @Override
    public void set(int row, int col, int digit) {
        if (row >= 0 && row < 9 && col >= 0 && col < 9) {
            board[row][col] = digit;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(int row, int col) {
        if (row > 9 || col > 9 || row < 0 || col < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        board[row][col] = 0;

    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                board[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void setMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
        if (matrix.length != 9 || matrix[0].length != 9) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } else {
            board = matrix;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int[][] getMatrix() {
        return board;
    }

    /**
     * Method for printing the board
     */
    public void printBoard() {
        for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
            if (row % 3 == 0 && row != 0) {
                System.out.println("---------------------");
            }
            for (int column = 0; column < 9; column++) {
                if (column % 3 == 0 && column != 0) {
                    System.out.print("|");
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.print(board[row][column]);
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean legal(int digit, int row, int col) {
        for (int i = 0; i < board[row].length; i++) { // check if the number is in the row
            if (board[row][i] == digit) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {// check if the number is in the column
            if (board[i][col] == digit) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        // For checking if the number is in the box
        int boxRow = row - row % 3;
        int boxCol = col - col % 3;
        for (int i = boxRow; i < boxRow + 3; i++) {
            for (int j = boxCol; j < boxCol + 3; j++) {
                if (board[i][j] == digit) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean solve() {
        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
                if (board[row][col] == 0) { // check for "empty" spots
                    for (int numberToTry = 1; numberToTry <= 9; numberToTry++) {
                        if (legal(numberToTry, row, col)) {
                            set(row, col, numberToTry);
                            if (solve()) { // recursive call of the solve method
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                set(row, col, 0);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

`

Hi, so this is a project im doing in school and im pretty far from finished. However at the moment my solver seem to work pretty much as intended although i cant get the UI to work. It can display the sample sudoku i have in the constructor aswell as solve it, but i cant change the board by reading inputs from the ui.

When i change something in the UI and the press the solve button it just changes everything back to how the sample board i started with would be solved.
Any tips? My guess is that either the implementation of SetAction is wrong or the way i try to read the JTextFields is wrong?

I tried all the functions of the SudokuBoard class in a main with the "printboard" function and it seems to be working there.

EDIT : The interface SudokuSolver is from the assignment, it just contains the methods we gotta have in our solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program does work—if you remember to press Enter after changing a cell’s value.

The problem is here:

```
temp.addActionListener(new SetAction(row, col, temp, board));
```

That line is correct, but it’s not enough.  A JTextField’s ActionListener is invoked when the user presses Enter in that JTextField.  If the user never presses Enter, the ActionListener is never called.

You can force it to be called by using [InputVerifier](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html):

```
SetAction setAction = new SetAction(row, col, temp, board);
temp.addActionListener(setAction);

temp.setInputVerifier(new InputVerifier() {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(JComponent component) {
        setAction.actionPerformed(null);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah that makes alot of sense! although when trying that i can only put inputs in the first box ie [0] [0], when i try clicking the others nothing happens?

Comment: Are you sure you’re returning `true` from the InputVerifier’s verify method?  Returning false will prevent the field from losing focus.

Comment: I had it as false :D now it allows me to click all the boxes but now i get an error when calling the solve method. The UI now looks like this : https://pastebin.com/6PU7mYnz 
i get " Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at SudokuBoard.set(SudokuBoard.java:23)"

Comment: A `catch` block must *always* print an exception’s stack trace, either by logging the exception or by calling its `printStackTrace` method.  Also exceptions are supposed to inform a developer of what went wrong, so try something like `if (row < 0 || row >= 9) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid row: " + row);` (and of course do the same for `col`).  You might even want to create a `private void checkLocation(int row, int col)` method that both `set` and `remove` can call.  And remember to pay attention that stack trace—it will tell you which code is passing in an invalid row or column.